# Change "Your Answer" to "Your Answer to this Question"

Tags: feature-request, flags, answers, not-an-answer

Many new users use the "Answer" section to *answer another answer*. It seems they (reasonably) assume the Stack Exchange sites work the way many forums and Facebook work: a chronological sequence of posts, whose order is static, so an "answer" posted under another answer would make sense if you wanted to respond to an answer.

Not being familiar with how Stack Exchange works, the "Your Answer" link is the only active link that fits the meaning of "I want to post something".

This is actually not unreasonable, because "Your Answer" is ambiguous: Your answer *to what*?

Although a bit wordy, "Your Answer to this Question" would make it clear to new users what "Answer" means in Stack Exchange sites (and reduce the number of NAA flags!)

---

I am not precious about the exact text to change it to, but the meaning should be clear and unambiguous.

Comment: +1 On GIS SE the current wording on that button is "Add Another Answer" but I agree that "Add Another Answer to the Question" would make what is about to be done even clearer.

Comment: As a frequent NAA flagger on [android.se], I support this request, since many one-time users think it as a forum and thus thinking an answer as *reply* to a post.

Comment: When new users try to answer, they are shown a scrolling message with "Please be sure to *answer the question*".

Comment: @fund and yet so many (apparently) ignore that. Maybe, having decided to click "answer", their mind is at that instant made up, and any message after that point is just noise. There's probably a PhD in it, but nevertheless, the evidence shows they post facebook sytle NAA answers